# Structure member as function template pointer with unspecified template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Is there a possibility to declare a structure member as a pointer to a function template without specifying the template parameter(s)?
Use case: I have a struct that holds data about function parameters. One of the members of this struct is a pointer to a function that converts the incoming data from a JSON to native C++ data. I want to be able to fill this struct with data according to the needs but don't want to write functions for every possible types. Consider the following scenario:

The described function is this:

```
void modifySomeValueAndMeta(double *value, int *meta);
```

For additional clarification, assume that the function gets those parameters, works some magic, and modifies them. After return, an other function (paramOut - omitted now for simplicity) would do the backwards native -> JSON conversion.
Here are the stuff needed to describe the possible parameters:

```
template<typename T> void (*PFN_PARAM_IN)(T* dst, json &param);

typedef struct Parameter
{
    const char *name;
    const char *type;
    const char *rawType;
    const PFN_PARAM_IN paramIn; // compiler error of course
} Parameter;

template<typename T> void myParamIn(T *dst, json &param)
{
    *dst = param.get<T>();
}
```

And finally the description of the two parameters of the function:

```
Parameter paramDesc_getValue[] =
{
    { "value", "double *", "double", myParamIn<double> },
    { "meta", "int *", "int", myParamIn<int> }
};
```

This of course doesn't compile, but I don't want to specify the template parameter inside the declaration of the Parameter structure, instead I want to be able to specify it in the literal, and with different type at each array element. Can I somehow solve this with C++, or do I have to modify it to make dst void * and create every possible functions beforehand?

Comment: In short no, a function template isn't something that exists. A *function* exists, after it's been generated from a template with specific template args. What are you trying to implement, a poor-mans reflection into JSON or a JSON parser? If the latter, consider using an existing one like [rapidjson](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson).

Comment: No, i'm trying to implement kind of a testing framework. It would get it's commands through a socket, in JSON, like "call this function with these parameters". Also the configuration of this testing framework would be generated by a python script parsing the header file.